# Cannot resolve symbol 'android'

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have some errors. For exemple at this line: android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;  word 'android' is colored in red, and I have an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'android' " 
The same thing with word 'microedition' from this line: import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

Can you help me with this problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which IDE do you use and how did you get it configured ? Follow some tutorial to get started with the ADT plugin.

Comment: How can I see which version of IDE I use ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Intellij Idea